# SwiftUI List NavigationView onDelete alert confirmation has ugly animation

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

The problem is that whenever you put the list in navigationView, the animation of the delete cancelation of the list row is not so nice. Am I doing something wrong in my `body` property?

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(self.contacts){ contact in
                    ContactRow(contact: contact)
                }.onDelete { self.setDeletIndex(at: $0) }
            }
            .alert(isPresented: $showConfirm) {
                Alert(title: Text("Delete"), message: Text("Sure?"),
                      primaryButton: .cancel(),
                      secondaryButton: .destructive(Text("Delete")) {
                        
                        self.delete()
                      })
            }
            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
            .navigationTitle("Contacts")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: HStack {
                Button("Add", action: self.addItem)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A late response, but might help people in the future.

This solution requires iOS 15.0 and above, and your `Contact` model to conform to `Hashable`.

We can get rid of this weird animation by stopping using the `onDelete` method altogether and using `swipeActions` instead. We could do it as follows:

```
    List {
        ForEach(Array(contacts.enumerated()), id: \.element) {
            index, contact in
            ContactRow(contact: contact)
                .swipeActions {
                    Button(action: {
                        indexToDelete = index
                        showConfirm = true
                    }) {
                        Text("Delete")
                    }
                    .tint(.red)
                }
        }
    }
    .alert(isPresented: $showConfirm) {
        Alert(
            title: Text("Delete"),
            message: Text("Sure?"),
            primaryButton: .cancel(),
            secondaryButton: .destructive(Text("Delete")) {
                self.delete()
            }
        )
    }
```

Comment: main reason of issue is `.destructive` button role. No need to avoid using `.onDelete` modifier.

Comment: This issue also happen if you wrap content with `NavigationStack` instead `NavigationView`

Comment: I didn't have chance to take a look, but please, feel free to submit an edit if this answer is wrong or misleading :)